# ryu installation error due to invalid syntax in setup.py file

Tags: python, mininet, ryu

I tried to install ryu in mininet using `pip install ryu`.
However, the following error showed up:
in a setup.py there is invalid syntax error (pic shown below)
[syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTNCf.png)

I have tried with `sudo pip install ryu`. It worked but root installation of ryu cannot be used for the required purpose (`/var/log/ryu/ryu` not found if ryu installed in root).

Comment: It looks like you're still on Python 2. That hit EOL years ago and is no longer supported. You need a more recent Python.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use git?
install Ryu from the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/faucetsdn/ryu.git
cd ryu; pip install .
```

Requirements:

```
pip install -r tools/optional-requires
```

I recommend following the links below:
[1]: https://ryu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html
[2]: https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/Ryubook.pdf
[3]: https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/
[4]: https://www.obriain.com/training/sdn/RYU_Soft_Testbed_v1.6_odt.pdf
[5]: https://www.obriain.com/training/sdn/RYU_Soft_Testbed_v2.0.pdf